# XamDateTimeEditor spin button click set focus

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I am using XamDateTimeEditor for time (hh:mm) masking. Now when cursor focus is in control then its works on spin button up and down.But cursor focus is in other control and i click on spin Button (up or down) nothing happened. So how can i set focus in my current control when click on spin Button (up or down).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the very same question is already answered in the Infragistics' forums:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/79746.aspx